# Aerospike: 1422:LDT-Sub Record Open Error

Tags: aerospike

I was using Aerospike 3.5.4  During write operation I hit HWL and write stopped.  Hence increased the space and restarted the servers (2node, replication 2)  After which I am not able to read/write on some of the huge LDT bins.  I am using Large stack.

1. I knew LStack has been depricated. How to migrate existing data from LStack to LList.
2. How to recover this corrupted LDT bins.

Currently upgraded the server to 3.6.3

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Update: I am unable to read LDT bins even after upgrade to 3.6.3.   Looks like a bug related to this has been fixed in 3.6.x

Answer (score 2):

Recommend taking a look at the List operations introduced in 3.7. These are native calls to manipulate list and may satisfy your use case.

We have found LDT to be sub-optimal in many of the cases we've seen. Both from a performance perspective (Lua/UDF used) and complexity perspective.

Regarding tactical solutions for the corruption. It would be best to remove the record and start afresh.

Comment: @ wchu,Thanks for your reply.  My problem is I should be able to get that record some how to clear and re-insert. Any ways I can recover or lost is lost.