# Aerospike: How to migrate data from LSTACK to LLIST

Tags: aerospike

I am currently using Aerospike 3.6.3 and using LSTACK to store user events. As LSTACK has been deprecated, and Aerospike team suggest to use LLIST, can someone help in migrating data from LSTACK to LLIST?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Aerospike 3.7.0 introduced list manipulation functionality on server side and the corresponding client API. You can use it as a stack and do push/pop operations of the list. You need to read the old data from LSTACK and push it to the new list.

Comment: Thanks Sunil. My use case is, I have a LStack bin called "envents" with key 55. Similarly I have 1000s of bins with corresponding keys.  Please suggest how do I migrate without affecting production code? A downtime can be accepted.   Migrating to different bin may lead to code changes.  Also can pls you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037121/aerospike-1422ldt-sub-record-open-error.